# Thread polling sqs and adding it to a python queue for processing dies

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, amazon-sqs

I have a piece of multi threaded code - 3 threads that polls data from SQS and add it to a python queue. 5 threads that take the messages from python queue, process them and send it to a back end system.

Here is the code:

```
python_queue = Queue.Queue()

class GetDataFromSQS(threading.Thread):
    """Threaded Url Grab"""
    def __init__(self, python_queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.python_queue = python_queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.5) //sleep for a few secs before querying again
            try:
                msgs = sqs_queue.get_messages(10)
                if msgs == None:
                    print "sqs is empty now"!
                for msg in msgs:
                    #place each message block from sqs into python queue for processing
                    self.python_queue.put(msg)
                    print "Adding a new message to Queue. Queue size is now %d" % self.python_queue.qsize()
                    #delete from sqs
                    sqs_queue.delete_message(msg)
            except Exception as e:
                print "Exception in GetDataFromSQS :: " +  e


class ProcessSQSMsgs(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, python_queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.python_queue = python_queue
        self.pool_manager = PoolManager(num_pools=6)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            #grabs the message to be parsed from sqs queue
            python_queue_msg = self.python_queue.get()
            try:
                processMsgAndSendToBackend(python_queue_msg, self.pool_manager)
            except Exception as e:
                print "Error parsing:: " + e
            finally:
                self.python_queue.task_done()

def processMsgAndSendToBackend(msg, pool_manager):
    if msg != "":
        ###### All the code related to processing the msg
        for individualValue in processedMsg:
            try:
                response = pool_manager.urlopen('POST', backend_endpoint, body=individualValue)
                if response == None:
                    print "Error"
                else:
                    response.release_conn()
            except Exception as e:
                print "Exception! Post data to backend: " + e


def startMyPython():
    #spawn a pool of threads, and pass them queue instance
    for i in range(3):
        sqsThread = GetDataFromSQS(python_queue)
        sqsThread.start()

    for j in range(5):
        parseThread = ProcessSQSMsgs(python_queue)
        #parseThread.setDaemon(True)
        parseThread.start()

    #wait on the queue until everything has been processed
    python_queue.join()
    # python_queue.close() -- should i do this?

startMyPython()
```

**The problem:**
3 python workers die randomly (monitored using top -p  -H) once every few days and everything is alright if i kill the process and start the script again. I suspect the workers that vanish are the 3 GetDataFromSQS threads.. And because the GetDataFromSQS dies, the other 5 workers although running always sleep as there is no data in the python queue. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here as I am pretty new to python and followed this tutorial for creating this queuing logic and threads - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/

Thanks in advance for your help. Hope I have explained my problem clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem for the thread hanging was related to getting a handle of the sqs queue. I used IAM for managing credentials and the boto sdk for connecting to sqs.

The root cause for this issue was that the boto package was reading the metadata for auth from AWS and it was failing once in a while.

The fix is to edit the boto config, increasing the attempts that are made to perform the auth call to AWS.

[Boto]
metadata_service_num_attempts = 5

( https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/boto-users/1yX24WG3g1E )